# CTRL + arrows not working in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

I've Office 365 for enterprise (version 2008, build 13127.21216) on a HP Elitebook with Windows 10 (1909).

CTRL + left / right arrow shortcuts (for jumping one word) does not work in Outlook. When I press them, just nothing happens.
The issue is the same for both pressing the dedicated arrow keys, or pressing 4 / 6 when numlock is turned off.

Those work correctly in all other applications including Office (Excel, Word..) and also browsers, notepad++ ...

All others shortcuts working well also in Outlook, even CTRL + Shift + left / right.

The problem is so odd, that I'm not sure whether it's a driver issue, some other activities linked to that shortcut (I don't have any shortcut manager installed) or a bug in Outlook.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start and stop Read aloud function, it works for me. [Read aloud button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVs4d.png)

More about function: https://www.howtogeek.com/394820/how-to-use-or-hide-outlooks-read-aloud-tool/
It somehow messes with Ctrl arrow shorcut.

Comment: Indeed it is related to read aloud function. It can be activated by AltGr + Space which sometimes I press by chance. When it's active I my shortcuts doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did this issue occurred only recently? As I know, the issue may occur if you installed any add-ins that cause the shortcut key to not work, it's suggested to run your outlook in safe mode to test if it could work normally.

According to my tests on my Outlook 365 version 2101 (Current Channel) and version 2012(Monthly Enterprise Channel), ctrl+arrow could work normally there, considering you are working with Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel Office, in order to avoid the version issue, maybe you could try to change your channel and update your Outlook version to check if the issue has any difference.